# Convert Array<string> to Record<Enum> in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Having

```
export enum PropertyCode {
  _D = '_D',
  ABCO = 'ABCO',
  ACC = 'ACC',
  // ... etc
```

I have a function that should return a `Record<PropertyCode, any>`

```
public getProperties(): Record<PropertyCode, any> {

    let propertyArray: [PropertyCode, any][] = this.propertyControls?.map(
        (x) => [x.value.propertyCode, x.value.value]) ?? [];

    return propertyArray // [string, any][] ==>??? Record<PropertyCode, any> 
}
```

I have a compile error :

> Type '[PropertyCode, any][]' is missing the following properties from
> type 'Record<PropertyCode, any>': _D, ABCO, ACC, ACCO, and 255 more.

How should I convert the array to Record, without explicitly filling all 255 enum codes?

Comment: Map callback returns an array of tuples whereas you want to return a hashmap object. Consider using `Array.prototype.reduce`. Please provide reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try it with `.reduce`:

```
return propertyArray.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr[0]] = curr[1]
  return acc
}, {} as Record<PropertyCode, any>)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ssl=14&ssc=41&pln=11&pc=5#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwApQmYsCeAwhACbBwDeAUHHAPoAicAvHAOSNsA0NcAggCFCAeRbtBI7rz6FCYtjMJSAvlSoAzZIgDGMAJYREcAObAYWHHn3AAzgAoAlAC44AJWDboJADwXcBYjIuOABDRHwAPko1WlpPRBt4MGx-GHw%20KCgQ-BcAbT8rIlJgYLD8AF1c8rEqmNioM2QoI2TLAgys-AA6BpJkbWA7OxDtbWDtJqgHFijqWNiR7VyJzNyABnLq1hWoXIBGct55hpgmo0WjuGVgimVQmzcPL18UwsCS0PCI6aplIA)

Comment: what about `const properties = Object.assign({}, ...values.map((x) => ({ [x.propertyCode]: x.value })));`

Answer (score 1):

As @captain-yossarian correctly notes, you can't use `map`, since it doesn't return a `Record`. You'll need to do it yourself, and also decide what to do in case of a duplicate keys. Below example shows it, both without and with using `array.reduce` (I personally don't find it adds to readability, YMMV).

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBACgTgewA7DgFwJ4GEEBNhQDeAUFGVAPoAiUAvFAOTUMA0p5AggEJYDydjbn1bsyHLFgENxWEeSgB6BVAB0aqMDQBjYgF9ixAJYg0qAGYBDLQXjJUmHCcQAbIqKgA3C87DAAXG7y8kiIKOjYeP6wofYR+ADc7vJePlEAzmhwxgDmifL6+sRaCCAZUCF24Y6ZCM5pAbZhDiU1zgDaALoCbe6Ent6+AX0VTXFRjbE4+CrULP2pAQwARgxQumts8kqqapo6HYnEZmAgWmiGJVDZmhPohsBpABQAlAEASsDFcLgAPLfN+DmFhAGAAfIFyMVSmgoFYtAJCOsLGkoB8vr9-mMgSDQXlyGYEHAoI8oWUtGA4ESEGZyjEqi0XGlnhCglBDDTHnC2uTKSoUr4VCNJpEOsySKzWWgABaIADuUAABrgwEhnIYtBZTLTKgCCAASQg8uB8gbAQV03W6BV41n6CWwrRabkU438s1C+n4Lr0I0m1J+3w2tYGeRwTQUkAOrSJQrHU7nS7XND-e5pACqaRyH2V1he70+hIxFqxsJxLKgYbQEe1o2qjJUYZzwEenMdcyNzNo4PFEvZxK5vrd5p1Y1F5ft0rliuVqvVmoIHt1UANg9Nw9rkStQfySXIA5dAfdxamwG9UFX-rd2-IlercKDujmiNhKLRhb+x8i2LBzxjBlJtRms4CDZI8SYpg8Ly-kUJRpIBKjAaB4EWqmGZZsATZQfEQA)

```
enum PropertyCode {
    _D = '_D',
    ABCO = 'ABCO',
    ACC = 'ACC',
    // ... etc
}

interface PropertyControl {
    value: {
        propertyCode: PropertyCode;
        value: string;
    }
}

const propertyControls: PropertyControl[] = [
    { value: { propertyCode: PropertyCode._D, value: 'b' } },
    // ...etc
];

function getProperties(): Record<PropertyCode, any> {
    const acc = {} as Record<PropertyCode, any>;
    for (const curr of propertyControls) {
        if (acc[curr.value.propertyCode]) {
            throw `duplicate propertyCode ${curr.value.propertyCode}`;
        }
        acc[curr.value.propertyCode] = curr.value.value;
    }

    return acc;
}

function getPropertiesUsingReduce(): Record<PropertyCode, any> {
    return propertyControls.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        if (acc[curr.value.propertyCode]) {
            throw `duplicate propertyCode ${curr.value.propertyCode}`;
        }
        acc[curr.value.propertyCode] = curr.value.value;
        return acc;
    }, {} as Record<PropertyCode, any>);
}

console.log(getProperties());
console.log(getPropertiesUsingReduce());
```